# How to solve ReactJs Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I get this error when I tried to use react router and I notice in my reactjs environment everything working but when I run npm run build file that time the react router does not working,

Here is full error which I see my console need to fix it.

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in TextTypeEffect (at carousel.js:8)
    in div (at carousel.js:7)
    in div (at carousel.js:6)
    in Carousel (at App.js:71)
    in Home (at App.js:41)
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens when your component tries to set the state after the component unmounts, so you need to unsubscribe the state updates in `componentWillUnmount()`
Below is the sample code for Class Components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {

    _isMounted = false;

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount = () => this._isMounted = false;

    setState = (state, callback) => this._isMounted && super.setState(state, callback);
}
```

Comment: can you give me with documentation so that I can learn this topic, I little bit of confuse about reactjs lifecycle. I have used componentDidMount for update the setInterval some object.

Comment: For component lifecycles, you can read https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/lifecycle_methods_overview.html this article, they have explained it really well.

Answer (score 0):

Try unsubscribing your state, inside the component the error is appearing in: 
e.g.

```
 const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false); 

    useEffect(() => {
     setDidMount(true);
     //You need to unsubscribe before un-mounting component
     return () => setDidMount(false);
    }, [])
```